# Comparing a large set of images by content

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am running a server using Flask (Python) that allows users to upload images. (Eventually images will be sent to an S3 bucket; for now, they're just saved to disk.) However, I want to prevent duplicate and similar images.

This means that each time that a user attempts to upload an image, I have to search through the database (in a fashion similar to [tineye](http://tineye.com/)). If a similar result exists, the app will not upload the image. Is this type of "reverse image search" possible with just the Python Imaging Library? Are there other Python frameworks out there that have been used to accomplish similar tasks? Or perhaps an Amazon tool?

Comment: Duplicates is easy, you can just store and search use md5 sums, but "similar" is much more difficult.

Comment: It looks like you got a very useful answer, here... but don't get fixated on *"the app will not upload the image,"* because -- at scale, and depending on your motivation -- it may be more appropriate to go ahead and allow the upload for the moment, and detect/deal with any duplication in the background. What if the new image is, for example, higher quality than the one you already have?  You probably don't want to slow down the 99.999% of uploads that are legitimate, but this depends heavily on why you need to deduplicate.  Storage is cheap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the image library create a finger print of unique images.If a new image comes in check against the finger prints and take the decision appropriately.

For fingerprinting refer this 
https://realpython.com/blog/python/fingerprinting-images-for-near-duplicate-detection/

If you want to bring AI here,
Look out for autoencoder.

Comment: Create a fingerprint how? Will the fingerprint be the same for "similar" images, such as the same image resized?

Comment: Refer this https://realpython.com/blog/python/fingerprinting-images-for-near-duplicate-detection/