# S3 - Detect Duplicate Images

Tags: php, amazon-s3

What is the best way to detect duplicate images on S3?

High level: Should I check on upload first. Or, upload first, then periodically prune for duplicates. Or...

Low level: What's the best way to actually check for duplicate images, specifically randomly generated names that might be the same visual content. [Note, ideally, there would be a more certain way than Etag and size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063801/how-to-find-duplicate-files-in-an-aws-s3-bucket) as many of these images may be very similar in content and size.

I'm trying to optimize, of course, for lowering resource cost :)

Comment: I think an Etag is fairly certain - the images being "very similar in content and size" will not generate identical Etags, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Edit: There's no specification for the generation method of Etags in the http specs, so I guess the Etag algorithm used can (in principle) produce either many, few or no collisions.

Comment: Etag is safe to use since it's always a hash. Take a look at http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.s3.s3tools/583 and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html

Comment: Similar, but not a duplicate, since it's python specific: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43859739/1695906

Comment: ETags doesn't seem to work for identical objects  https://www.kurokatta.org/grumble/2020/02/aws-s3-etag